# How Spark writes/reads process through spark-Cassandra connector different from CQLSH read/write process

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

I am new to spark , trying to understand , how is spark advantageous when using it through spark-Cassandra connector on Cassandra cluster.

1. How does write (example savetocassandra) to Cassandra works through spark-Cassandra connector (spark SQL queries , does it involve coordinator node still?
2. How does read to Cassandra works through spark-Cassandra connector (spark SQL queries) , does it involve coordinator node still?
3. what makes spark overcome the load of  Cassandra , during high range read scans on the cluster?
4. How does a high  range scan cql read query gets executed on Cassandra cluster through spark-Cassandra connector?
5. using IN clause through spark-Cassandra connector on Cassandra cluster is advantage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good explanation. I also recommend other Russell talks, if you want to understand spark-cassandra-connector internals 
Cassandra and Spark Optimizing for Data Locality - Russell Spitzer (DataStax)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikCzILOpYvA